# Refactoring/cleaningup time function in django view

Tags: python, django

I have the following view in my django app that works perfectly. I am pretty new to python/django. I want to refactor this so that I have a function that handles the time encoding and I can just call it so that my view is not so cluttered.

```
@csrf_exempt
def emulate_create(request):
    args = json.loads(request.body, object_hook=utils._datetime_decoder)
    resourceId, count, hours = args['resourceId'], args['count'], args['hours']
    now = timezone.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    remainder = now.minute % 15
    delta = (15 - remainder)
    timeFrom = now + timedelta(minutes=delta)
    timeTo = timeFrom + timedelta(hours=hours)

    reservation = ReservationProspect(byUser=request.user, forUser=request.user, resource=get_object_or_404(Resource, uuid=resourceId), modality=get_object_or_404(Modality, name="online"), timeFrom=timeFrom, timeTo=timeTo, count=count)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps([reservation.toDict()], default=utils._datetime_encoder))
```

How would I go about refectoring this? I think this is the part that should be extracted into a function:

```
now = timezone.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
remainder = now.minute % 15
delta = (15 - remainder)
timeFrom = now + timedelta(minutes=delta)
timeTo = timeFrom + timedelta(hours=hours)
```

How would you go about this? What should the functions return and how would you call it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def time_encode(hours):
    now = timezone.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    remainder = now.minute % 15
    delta = (15 - remainder)
    timeFrom = now + timedelta(minutes=delta)
    timeTo = timeFrom + timedelta(hours=hours)
    return (timeFrom, timeTo)
```

This would be a good starting point. The function returns a tuple (two results) and can be used in the following way.

```
@csrf_exempt
def emulate_create(request):
    args = json.loads(
        request.body,
        object_hook=utils._datetime_decoder
    )
    resourceId, count, hours = args['resourceId'], args['count'], args['hours']

    timeFrom, timeTo = time_encode(hours)

    reservation = ReservationProspect(
        byUser=request.user,
        forUser=request.user,
        resource=get_object_or_404(Resource, uuid=resourceId),
        modality=get_object_or_404(Modality, name="online"),
        timeFrom=timeFrom,
        timeTo=timeTo,
        count=count
     )

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(
            [reservation.toDict()],
            default=utils._datetime_encoder
        )
    )
```